# There is a way in Tumblr to get media images URL in the same domain of the blog name?

Tags: api, cross-domain, subdomain, tumblr, getimagedata

Lets say my blog is `http://foo.tumblr.com`.

All the post's images are stored in `xx.media.tumblr...` (for example: `https://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_250.jpg`) (first 2 numbers can be skipped)

But i want the URL of the image be in the same domain of my blog, and looks something like this:

```
http://foo.tumblr.com/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_250.jpg
```

(that doesn't exist)

Why i need that? I  am creating a script, and it generates a `canvas` that detects if the image have transparency with a `getImageData` (all the `.jpg` are skipped), but since the subdomain is different, i get a cross-domain security error, and the `canvas` is tainted, avoiding the use of `getImageData`.

So.. how can i do that?

I think Tumblr API could be useful, but how?

Comment: I don't think its possible, as you mention Tumblr servers all its images from `media.tumblr.com` more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832963/url-schema-of-tumblr-images/16836223#16836223

Answer (score 0):

Scrape your sitemap for all posts and get their images. You could use the API or just with Javascript in the browser console:

```
xmlin = prompt(); // view-source:biochemistri.es/sitemap1.xml
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlin,"text/xml");
xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('loc')[0].remove();
posts = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('loc');
postlist = [];
for (i=0;i<posts.length;i++) {postlist.push(posts[i].innerHTML)};
```

...to generate an array containing all posts, which can be navigated through for photo posts (`div.post.photo`) and their URLs copied.

Then simply generate a new list of images with a for loop and `newImg = document.createElement('img')`, setting an `origin` attribute using `newImg.setAttribute('origin') = myPhotoList[n]` which can then be used to select an image programmatically:

```
document.querySelector("img[origin='"+{PhotoURL-HighRes}+"']"
```

(or `{PhotoURL-1280}`, `{PhotoURL-500}`, `{PhotoURL-250}` etc. Once retrieved over an XMLHttpRequest, you could simply switch the post in the DOM. The `{PhotoURL-HighRes}` in my example above wouldn't work, it'd be an attribute from the page I'm just indicating which part you'd want to get from the theme HTML.

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832963/url-schema-of-tumblr-images), there is a variable which could be used as a more concise attribute than the full origin URL if you want to be a bit more specific with regular expressions.

This would effectively put all of your images onto your local URL, with URLs like `foo.tumblr.com/images/tumblr_kzjlfiTnfe1qz4rgho1_250.jpg`, and avoid cross-domain restrictions. I'm guessing it'd work only if you don't have a **ton** of posts as custom pages such as you'd be using to store images do have a restriction on their size (though I suppose you could make a second one).

Also might be sensible to include CSS to set `display: none` in case anyone stumbles upon the page by accident, and a redirect function to the homepage with `window.onload` or similar.