# Discover the Tumblr page by a URL

Tags: image, url, tumblr

There is any way to know a Tumblr address deconding the URL from a image?

I have this decoded URL:

http://41.media.tumblr.com/bc74a06048a7e52db8aa875c6400cfc6/tumblr_nekge3qHr91t025dco5_500.jpg

I had already try to find from where it is by using google image search, without any results.

There iso any way to know the Tumblr who posted this image by this URL?

I had alreadly seen this post ([What is the URL schema of Tumblr images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832963/what-is-the-url-schema-of-tumblr-images)) that explain how the URL are done. But it doens't do any clue about where is located the image or how to decode the Tumblr address.

Comment: simple; inspect the element (F12), and look at the img `src`

Comment: The src is exactly this URL. It doesn't give any more informations about where the file is located. I guess that the location of the file is encrypted inside this URL ( on this part bc74a06048a7e52db8aa875c6400cfc6/tumblr_nekge3qHr91t025dco5_500.jpg )

Comment: Look at this: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=http:%2F%2F41.media.tumblr.com%2Fbc74a06048a7e52db8aa875c6400cfc6%2Ftumblr_nekge3qHr91t025dco5_500.jpg

Answer (score 1):

https://redirect.media.tumblr.com/image?url= and then your image link without the http media tumblr.com part.

So in your case it would be https://redirect.media.tumblr.com/image?url=/bc74a06048a7e52db8aa875c6400cfc6/tumblr_nekge3qHr91t025dco5_500.jpg

Comment: Addendum, as of sometime between 17th and 27th June 2019, this method no longer works.

Comment: Addendum 2, as of I-don't-know-when, refreshing an image page will yield the account url. Use that and the archive thing to check when the image is posted for the original source.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way. Using reverse image search engine TinEye!

But there is no way to find the Tumblr by a post image URL because the URL is for a central Tumblr image server, so it not correspond to the address of who posted.